# Apache Rewrite custom rules file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a server set up hosting a website. It uses "pretty links". I am having a problem when trying to create rules in the htaccess file.

Before I continue I would like to reference the locations I use to minimise confusion

- `wwww/` the wwww is the site all my folders content in and it resides in the www folder created by wamp
- `page.php` contains the rules I want to somehow impliment and this is located in the root of my website

currently my website produces links like the following which dont work:
`www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk/our-services`

the link above does not work but if I manually edit the link and do this it works:
`www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk/page.php?q=our-services`

I need to find a way to implement this in the htaccess file and get it to add the `page.php?q=`

Below is my htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . wwww/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The problem I am having is on my home page the navigation is generated and if I click a link for our services it redirects to the page `www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk/our-services`

What I need it to do is to hit my rule file which is in my root directory called `page.php` which in turn will use the `our-services` or whatever the query might be to give it the correct link

I know my htaccess file is currently linking back to the index file and this is why it isn't working but I have tried other methods as seen below.

---

ATTEMPT 1 - this just 404's or takes me to a blank page

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . wwww/page.php?q=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

---

ATTEMPT 2

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .? /page.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

My other attempts are all similar and I get the same 404 or blank screen. This is my first time getting into Rewriting links which explains my lack of knowledge about it.

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot`? Where is `page.php` located and what is `wwww` here?

Comment: @anubhava in my root the www folder i have another folder called wwww which contains all my website content css javascript etc. and page.php is located in the root of wwww the same folder my index is in and htaccess :)

Comment: So how to access a css file inside `/wwww/`? Is it `www.MYDOMAIN.co.uk/wwww/css/style.css` for example?

Comment: I am only hosting locally so at the minute it would go into the `www/wwww/css/style.css`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this rule from `/wwww/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wwww/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ page.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

If `/wwww/` is indeed your `DocumentRoot` then change `RewriteBase` line to:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Comment: Hi, his appears to work but some of my pages do not work with it because they are static, is there a way to exclude this rewrite for pages that already have a .php extensin?

Comment: Seems to work fine thanks a lot its hard to wrap my head around this :) please can you provide an explanation for me?

Comment: 2 conditions will skip any real files/directories for rewrite and `^([^.]+)$` will match any request that doesn't have DOT in it. It will rewrite to `page.php?q=<uri>`. `RewriteBase` sets current relative directory from `DocumentRoot`.